# Can't find an old IDE connector for Apple iBook G4 HDD

Tags: hard-drive, pata, ibook

I am asking it here because I did not know where to ask this question, looked it up and this is what I found:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange

I am looking for an IDE connector for Fujitsu MHT2030AT hdd (Apple ibook G4). I would be happy as long as it lets me connect to any of the today's technology USB, SATA, anything.

Here's what it looks like (Scale - centimeter)

[image]

The detailed manual of this hdd can be found here: 
http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/COMP/fcpa/hdd/discontinued/mht20xxat_prod-manual.pdf

It's basically a 44 pin connector. So far I have tried a couple of 44 pin connectors on eBay Australia but none of them are were thin enough to fit this disk.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Why has this been downvoted without any reasoning? I did my research and just the device mentioned in the answer was not available in any of the Australian stores so I just asked it here for a second opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a connector for a 2.5" IDE drive.

They will look something like this:

[image: 2.5" to 3.5" IDE connector]

You can find a list of compatible connectors here (depending on how you want to connect it):

http://www.ebay.com/bhp/laptop-ide-adapter

Or, you could buy something like this, which is more convenient, if you are going to use old hard drives on a regular basis:

[image: USB to IDE & SATA connector]

One of these options will let you connect a 2.5" IDE drive (which is what your picture shows) to a computer with either USB or 3.5" IDE or SATA (not shown in my pictures).

Comment: Can you please link to the second item? The female part looks quite thin here, something that I have not seen so far. A lot of sellers have said no to this hdd.

Comment: http://www.ambery.com/idesatousb20.html this is a standard component. From your picture, I'd say yours is standard also, but I cant guarantee it fits.

Comment: Cheers dude. I will accept this answer if it fits. Yeah, it looked pretty standard to me too when I took the case but realised that it's a lot thinner than the usual laptop hdds and those 4 jumper pins aren't helping.